# Which C++ vector push_back is called for objects created inside a loop

Tags: c++, vector, overloading, lvalue, rvalue

This is a very basic question, but I cannot seem to get my head around the logic of what is going on here. Consider the code snippet:

```
class Board{
private:
    vector< vector<Cell> > allCells;
    int bheight;
    int bwidth;
public:
    Board(int width = 10, int height = 10){
        bheight = height; bwidth = width;
        allCells.resize(width);
        #loop for creating cell objects
        for(int i = 0; i < width; i++){
            allCells[i].reserve(height);
            for(int j = 0; j < height; j++){
                Cell aCell(i,j,0); #an object created inside a loop
                allCells[i].push_back(aCell); #push it into a vector
            }

        }
    }
```

This code works fine i.e. after exiting the constructor, all the objects in the vector (of vectors) `allCells` still stores appropriate information. My question is how was this achieved? By definition, vector.push_back has only two variants:

```
void push_back (const value_type& val);
void push_back (value_type&& val);
```

It cannot call the second variant since the temporary `aCell` object is a lvalue object. If it calls the first variant, then it push the *temporary* object `aCell`, which is destroyed when the loop terminates.

Any explanation of what goes on under the hood of this is appreciated.

EDIT: code fixed due to error pointed out by  Sam Varshavchik and songyuanyao

Comment: [The new element is initialized as a copy of `value`.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back).

Comment: Ahh so the push_back object in the first variant is not the object created, but rather an object created by copy constructor of the argument?

Comment: Oops nvm, I misread. Sorry.

Comment: What's going on here is undefined behavior, and a bug. Which version of `push_back()` is being used is completely immaterial. The code is completely broken. Look up the difference between `reserve()` and `resize()`, and figure out which one you really need to use.

Comment: @ Sam Varshavchik sorry, it's a typo, i copy and pasted, fixed the snippet code through a few files to experiment before asking and the error creeped in. resize() was in my original code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If it calls the first variant, then it push the temporary object `aCell`, which is destroyed when the loop terminates.

Yes the 1st version is called since `aCell` is an lvalue. It's fine because the [push_back](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back)ed element is copy initialized from the argument; it's independent of the local variable `aCell`.

> Appends the given element value to the end of the container.
>
> 1) The new element is initialized as a copy of value.

BTW: Your code has undefined behavior when `allCells[i]` is used in the for loop, because `allCells` is still empty at that time, it has no elements. Note [reserve](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/reserve) won't change the size but the capacity of the `vector`, but [resize](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/resize) does.

```
Board(int width = 10, int height = 10){
    bheight = height; bwidth = width;
    allCells.reserve(width);           // it should be allCells.resize(width) !!
    #loop for creating cell objects
    for(int i = 0; i < width; i++){
        allCells[i].reserve(height);
        for(int j = 0; j < height; j++){
            Cell aCell(i,j,0); #an object created inside a loop
            allCells[i].push_back(aCell); #push it into a vector
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ahh thank you for the pointer about the bug in the code. just fixed it.